# Replacing Rails date_select with JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I've been trying to follow this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars

I've implemented the controls and all the javscript is working ... it loads a date into the field and it's submitted with the params, but rails is still inserting NULL into the date field. Here's what the log is showing:

```
Started POST "/shifts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-16 12:52:24 -0400
  Processing by ShiftsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"W1MmVDoKMuR3HKmql+dDdWXt70xmZ9bVOJgdUtb1lKQ=", "shift"=>{"shift_on"=>"06/23/2011", "state"=>"requested"}, "commit"=>"Create Shift"}
  SQL (0.3ms)   SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'

  AREL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "shifts" ("user_id", "shift_on", "state", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'requested', '2011-06-16 16:52:24.743149', '2011-06-16 16:52:24.743149')
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/shifts/1
Completed 302 Found in 274ms
```

The `shift_on` coloumn is a date type.

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@shift) do |f| %>
  <% if @shift.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@shift.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this shift from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @shift.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :shift_on %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :shift_on %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And this is my application.js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#shift_shift_on").datepicker();
});
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the generated daate i.e."06/23/2011" is not recognized so it inserts a null value. The date should be in a recognizable format such as "2011-6-23" etc.

To solve this issue, you can change the recieved date parameter shift_on to a ruby date by,

```
Date.strptime(shift_on, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Here,

```
Date.strptime("06/23/2011", "%m/%d/%Y") = Thu, 23 Jun 2011 which can then be stored in the Db.
```

Comment: I also was able to just update the jquery: `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' `

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the shift_on field as a Date? If you will need to parse it with Date.parse first otherwise you're trying to save a string in there.